# modx - can't change suffix for html

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have just installed the latest modx revo an my server. I also turned on SEO friendly URL.
My pages are now /page/subpage.html
Wanted to turn off the .html suffix but all the time a change it (no matter what I enter .htm / or empty) it'll show up and after I reload the settings page it changes to .html again.

There is a little red triangle (like in excel) in the upper left corner after I change it. What does that mean?

Flushed the cache several times as well.

Answer (score 2):

I thought modx updates this via AJAX - it looks like that. In the sys settings it works the same way. But I had to save it explicitly. Didn't see the save button at the top :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a system setting:

System -> Content Types -> Change .html to / or just blank.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was address & Solved here:

http://tracker.modx.com/issues/2279